# Lacewing headers issue

Tags: networking, protocols, liblacewing

I cannot resolve the Lacewing headers order. The first message to get send is as follows:

```
0
0
11 //lenght
0
..
```

while the Name set request is:

```
0
4 // lenght
1 // should be the type according to spec (1 for name setting request)
..
```

The lenght is stored at different bytes for these messages and so is the type of request. Maybe I have incorrect documentation but these message are what I am recieving.

Comment: Are the examples what you're sending or what you're receiving?

Answer (score 0):

From the protocol specification:
https://github.com/udp/lacewing/blob/0.2.x/relay/current_spec.txt

> As soon as the TCP connection is established, the client
>   should send a single byte of 0 to identify themselves
>   as a non-HTTP client.  After this, they may start
>   exchanging messages, of which the Connect request should
>   be the first.

On initial connection, non-HTTP clients send byte 0. This is not part of the message - the first actual protocol message comes after this.

> ```
> 0
> 0
> 11 //lenght
> 0
> ..
> ```

The first 0 is that "I'm not an HTTP client" identifier. The rest is the actual message: 0 is the type, which is made up of the variant and the request type type. The 11 is the length of the message, and the 0 is the actual "can I connect".

> ```
> 0
> 4 // lenght
> 1 // should be the type according to spec (1 for name setting request)
> ..
> ```

Again, 0 is the type, made up of the variant and request type. 4 is the length, again, and 1 is the request to Set Name.

The initial 0 on connection is a confusing aspect of the protocol because it is mentioned in an odd place, but it is mentioned, nonetheless.

Relevant thread in Development forum: http://community.clickteam.com/threads/79449-Lacewing-message-headers